# How can I use the python line_profiler with uwsgi?

Tags: python, uwsgi, line-profiler

Normally I would use the `@profile` decorator and run the script with `kernprof -l`. How can I do this for code that is executed through a uwsgi server?

It looks like you can add functions to be profiled through the line profiler api: `LineProfiler(my_fun)`. Maybe that will work? How would I dump the results to a file?

Comment: Were you able to find anything on your own here? Just trying to find any semblance of information regarding uWSGI and profiling.

Comment: No, I think I gave up.